# can't save files in .rb extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text, editor, scite

I'm a newb at Ruby. I installed it along with SciTe (which to my understanding no longer comes with the Installer pack..). I was prompted to insert some code to the ScitE editor and save it so I can then run the code...

The problem is that I can't save said file as (.rb). It's like the .rb option is gone. As if I diddn't have ruby.

This might be irrelevant but I was also prompted to add c:\ruby\bin to the system path so that SciTE can find the Ruby interpreter. All i need is to be able to save files in .rb

Moreover when prompted to ensure that Ruby is the language for SciTe nothing much happens...I'm unsure if a check mark is supposed to appear.

I'm incredibly frustrated over this. Help is appreciate.

Comment: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/204331 may be relevant. Can you confirm ruby has been installed successfully and is accessible on the system path? It's probably worth trying to run ruby from the command line to confirm it's installed correctly. Stay positive and keep at it! :-D

Comment: I wonder if the system is auto saving the extension, and you end up with files that look like `file.rb.rb`  The best way to see the files would likely be to open a console and do a `dir` to list the files and see what they list as.

Comment: are you able to run irb through console?